# check if all field hasClass error

Tags: jquery

```
$("input[type=text]").on('focusout', function(){
    if($(this).each().hasClass('valid')){
        alert('go');
    }
});
```

when the user finishing fill all the field, I want to check if the field passed my validation or not by check are each of them have class of 'valid' or not.. but in the console I got this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'call' of undefined
```

Comment: use if($(this).hasClass('valid')){

Comment: What about: `if(!$("input[type=text]").is('.error'))` supposing invalid fields get class error as your title suggest it

Answer (score 3):

`.each` method is used for iterating through jQuery collections, your usage of it is wrong, if you want to check that all of the inputs have class of `valid` you can either compare the length of the Input collection with the length of filtered `.valid` one. or use `.not()` method:

```
var $inputs = $("input[type=text]");

$inputs.on('blur', function(){
    if ( $inputs.length === $inputs.filter('.valid').length ) {
       // all fields are valid
    }
});
```

Using `.not()` method:

```
if ( !$inputs.not('.valid').length ) {
   // all fields are valid
} else {
   // at least one of them is not valid
}
```

Comment: The only valid answer is here!

Comment: sadly 2 field is type=password.. now what?

Comment: @MiguelaAnthony You can either select them using `input` selector: `$('input')` or be more specific `$("input[type=text], input[type=password]")`.